# How to get the path of an eclipse project in jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, maven, scriptlet

How to get the path  of my current project : it's a dynamic web application created with maven archetype .

I want to retrieve the path in my jsp page in scriptlet code , i used different codes but i'm always getting the path of eclipse (C:\Users\Amira\Desktop\eclipse\eclipse)
or the path of the web application on tomcat ((C:\software\apache-tomcat-7.0.28\apache-tomcat-7.0.28\wtpwebapps\TestProjectUI)

but i want the path of the project in my workspace : C:\Users\Amira\junoWorkspace\TestProjectUI

Any idea will be appreciated 
Thank you

Here's my jsp :

```
<body>

<%
if (request.getParameter("btnSubmit") != null) //btnSubmit is the name of your button,not id of that button.
{

    String className = request.getParameter("testclass");
    System.out.println(className);
    String[] command = {"CMD", "/C", "mvn -Dtest=" + className + " test"};
    ProcessBuilder probuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);

    //You can set up your work directory
    probuilder.directory(new File("C:\\Users\\Amira\\junoWorkspace\\TestProjectUI"));

    Process process = probuilder.start();

    //Read out dir output
    java.io.InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String line;
    System.out.printf("Output of running %s is:\n", Arrays.toString(command));
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }

    //Wait to get exit value
    try {
        int exitValue = process.waitFor();
        System.out.println("\n\nExit Value is " + exitValue);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
%>

        <html:file properties="tonFichier" name="tonForm"/>


        <p>   Please specify a Test :<br>
            <input type="file" name="testclass" size="40" >
        </p>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" value="Execute Test"/>

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Path, for what? The answer to this question may help!

Comment: @PaulVargas i'am running a maven test command so i have to access the path of the maven project first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever I have a problem like this, I print out all of the `System.getProperties()` and see if there is one that has the information I want. This is probably the best you can do here, since the only information provided by Eclipse will come through a property. If you don't have the information in one of the provided properties, you can provide it yourself as part of your launch configuration, you can use the `workspace_loc` variable in the launch config stuff.