# How to get eclipse root path in code?

Tags: java, eclipse

Can I **from code** get the absolute path of **Java** a project in **Eclipse** ex `C:\workspace\proj1`?

Thing is that code will be runned on different machines, so path will be different, depending on the machine.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: What sort of project? plugin? Java? C/C++? ....

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the path of an eclipse project in jsp page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11440705/how-to-get-the-path-of-an-eclipse-project-in-jsp-page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `System.getProperty("user.dir")` and find the directory from which the program is run.  If you look at the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty), you will get the description below:

```
user.dir    User's current working directory
```

**[SSCCE:](http://ideone.com/KLMWwF)**

```
public class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    }
}
```

Comment: @krzakov that's what I answered :)